# SQL: How do I select fields based on varying existing conditions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, conditional-statements

I'm facing a SQL problem that deals with selecting rows based on certain conditions. Example table below called 'users' as u:

```
id    category    label    date        rank count
111   weak        FFF      2014-06-01  1    4
111   strong      DDD      2014-06-02  2    4
111   strong      BBB      2014-06-03  3    4
111   weak        RRR      2014-06-04  4    4
222   weak        WWW      2014-07-01  1    3
222   weak        YYY      2014-07-02  2    3
222   weak        ZZZ      2014-07-03  3    3
```

There are two unique IDs (`111` and `222`). I want to retrieve the very last `u.label` for each `distinct ID` assuming all values under `users.category == 'weak'` (as in `ID 222`).

However, if there exists `'strong'` under `users.category`, return the `u.label` corresponding to the **latest** date where `users.category == 'strong'`.

Essentially, I'm looking for the following:

```
id    category    label    date      
111   strong      BBB      2014-06-03
222   weak        ZZZ      2014-07-03
```

What I've tried so far was a query with `"where rank=count"` to get the last record but I'm drawing a blank as to how I can select `u.label where category=='strong'` given its last record is `u.category=='weak'`, as in `ID 111`.

Thank you and please let me know if I can clarify any further!

Comment: What database / SQL engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL -- sorry to omit that!

Comment: What conditions need to be satisfied for a record to be identified as the **last record**?

Comment: So you need to rank records within each `id` group by the `category`, then descending `date`, then pick the first record in the group.

Comment: There are two ways to get last record:
1. If all values under u.category=='weak' for a given ID, select the record with the latest u.date (as in ID 222)
2. However, if 'strong' exists under u.category for a given ID, select the record with the latest u.date **and** u.category=='strong' (as in ID 111)

Comment: Table definition would help (`\d tbl` in psql). In particular, the data type of `category` and is it defined `NOT NULL`? Also, ` the very last u.label` is ambiguous. "Last" according to what? Also the latest date? Or `label`, alphabetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, may be:

```
select * from (
   select t.*, 
     row_number() over (
       partition by id 
       order by category asc, dt desc) rn
     from t
) tt where rn = 1;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/475d49/1/0

Comment: +1 for putting together a working SQL Fiddle in the said database (PostGres).

Answer (score 2):

No need for window functions

```
select distinct on (id) id, category, dt
from t
order by id, category = 'weak', dt desc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/475d49/3)

`false` sorts before `true` so when `category = 'weak'` it will sort last

You can add other columns to the select list. I just reused @mustaccio's Fiddle which has no `label` column.

Check `distinct on`:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: +1 for putting together a working SQL Fiddle in the said database (PostGres).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use row_number to order the records based on your criteria, i.e. order first by category ascending, then by date descending.

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (

    SELECT id, category, label, date, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY category ASC, date DESC) as ordinal_position
    FROM example
) x
WHERE ordinal_position = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f1b4f/2/0)

Comment: +1 for putting together a working SQL Fiddle in the said database (PostGres).